# CiviEvent registration being assigned to the the wrong participant

Tags: civievent, wordpress

I have created an event that allows for one person to register multiple participants. I pulled a report two days ago with the list of registrants and one person had paid the event fee plus a donation to total $35, which is unique for this event so far.
Today, someone new registered themselves and another person for the event and paid, which is fine. However, now that $35 registration has been assigned to the new registrant's name and not the correct original registrant. This has also happened in previous events I've created when I enable multiple registrations by one person. Does anyone know how I fix this? 
I'm running Civi 4.6.2 and latest version of wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are getting bit confused with Event registration 
When an Event is created to accept multiple participant

The first entered member is considered as the actual member register and he is the one who is charged for all the participant amount too (in respective of the member is new or existing)

I have done the same example against http://d46.demo.civicrm.org against Version 4.6.4 which is working alright - i don't think this is an issue

if you are still getting issue with this let me know with some example - thanks